# rsync webapps sub-directories

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat, rsync

Can I run tomcat as ec2-user? The issue is: I need to rsync some sub-folders of webapps folder between 2 ec2 instances. The rsync works for all folders owned by "ec2-user" but for the webapps sub-folders (whose owner is 'tomcat'), rsync fails with permission denied.
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

You could run rsync with `sudo`. ec2-user has sudo-without-a-password permissions.

i.e. `sudo rsync yourdir rsync://host/dst`